# Delete branch from source tree UI

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a question that I want to know the answer.
I am using source tree as git client.
In the branches I have a branch that I do not want to see.
My question is if I press it and select delete will it be deleted only from my UI. 
Or it will be removed completely from the server
I want to delete SeleniumFirstTask branch only from my UI.

[image]

Comment: Only for you. This is a local branch.

Comment: Your branch will be only deleted from the local repo and still the branch should exist in the remote repository.